# javascript objects are these all the same

Tags: javascript

What is the difference with the code below

1) are the first two constructors the same just with a different scope?

2) is the third object the same as the first two if they where instantiated as objects?

thanks for your help?

```
   function StaffMember(name){
        this.name = name;
        this.total = 0;
        this.discountPercent = function(){
            //do stuff
        };
    }

    StaffMember.prototype.calculateTax = function(){
    //work out tax

    };
```

or

```
var StaffMember = function(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.discountPercent = function(){
            //do stuff
    };
}

StaffMember.prototype.calculateTax = function(){
//work out tax

};
```

or

```
var StaffMember {
    name:"",
    discountPercent:function(){
            //do stuff
    },
    calculateTax : function(){
                     //work out tax

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Whats Happening

```
   function StaffMember(name){
        this.name = name;
        this.total = 0;
        this.discountPercent = function(){
            //do stuff
        };
    }

    StaffMember.prototype.calculateTax = function(){
    //work out tax

    };
```

That creates a constructor function and adds another function to its prototype.  If you then call `new StaffMember("bob")` it  will create an object with the local property name set to `bob`, a local property total set to 0, a local function discountPercent and a static function calculateTax

```
var StaffMember = function(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.discountPercent = function(){
            //do stuff
    };
}

StaffMember.prototype.calculateTax = function(){
//work out tax

};
```

This is equivalent to the above except without the total property.  Note that so far you have not created an instance of this StaffMember object that I think you're trying to create.  You've just defined a functon and put another function on its prototype

```
var StaffMember {
    name:"",
    discountPercent:function(){
            //do stuff
    },
    calculateTax : function(){
                     //work out tax

    }
}
```

This is invalid syntax, you need an `=` after StaffMember, but otherwise this will create an object with the name, discountPercent, and calculateTax properties.

This object will actually exist, since you've created it directly, for the others you'd need to call `var something = new StaffMember()`.

#### Differences

There is no significant difference between 1 and 2, other than where in the function these things are defined (the first example will be hoisted to the top of the current function scope, the second example won't be set until that point in the code).

Once you've called the `new StaffMember()` there will be some differences between the object you're creating and the object that you create directly in the 3rd example.

The most significant is that the prototype object will be shared among objects instead of being created new each time you create a new object.  Thats not super significant since you've just put a function on there, so actual performance will be the same, but it is will save some amount of memory, and it would act differently if you put an object like an array on the prototype.

Comment: thank you ....so is it correct to say that first two constructors would be used for if I was making a game an needed that object 500 times and the third would be for if I only needed it once?

Comment: Yes that would be correct.  Just make sure to actually instantiate them :)

Comment: @ben336: perhaps add a notice that there is a difference between 1&2 that could come into play when setting up longer inheritance chains: `StaffMember.prototype.constructor.name`... in the first example the constructor function has a name, the second example shows an annonymous function referenced by a var

Answer (score 2):

For the first 2 functions when you invoke them (the constructors) then they create objects. However they both share the function in prototype `calculateTax`. The last is an object already, an object literal which has the data and the functions.

```
function StaffMember(name){
        this.name = name;
        this.total = 0;
        this.discountPercent = function(){
            //do stuff
        };
}

StaffMember.prototype.calculateTax = function(){
    //work out tax
    console.log(this.total);
};

var objStaffMember = new StaffMember("User");
objStaffMember.total = 50;
objStaffMember.calculateTax();
```

Though the objects created would share the function `calculateTax`, when the function is actually called the context of `this` inside the `calculateTax` prototype function would be that object itself on which it is invoked. i.e. `objStaffMember` in the above case.

The small difference in the first 2 function is, because the second one has no name and it has a assignment, it is a function expression without a name, and the first one is function declaration and has a name.